# Browsing KcFinder in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, file-manager, kcfinder

I have problem making kohana work with kcfinder using textbox technique , it used to work before . Now I have problem It pop up with php code written in it

```
 function openKCFinder(base) {
window.KCFinder = {
    callBack: function(url) {
        $(".kc-file").val(url);
        $(".article-thumbnail").prop("src",url);
        window.KCFinder = null;
    }
};
window.open(base+'kcfinder/browse.php?type=files&dir=files/public', 'kcfinder_textbox',
    'status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, ' +
        'resizable=1, scrollbars=0, width=400, height=400'
);
}
```

base is  kohana base path

It shows me this

- `@copyright 2010, 2011 KCFinder Project * @license http:www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php GPLv2 * @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.php LGPLv2 * @link http://kcfinder.sunhater.com */ require "core/autoload.php"; $browser = new browser(); $browser->action(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks silly mistake of not processing PHP scripts.

Maybe you are referring to the disk and not to the web server?

`base` should be `http://...` not `c:\xaamp\...\`